# NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

This is the error I keep getting:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I understand that the error is saying that I am calling NSMutableArray functionality on a NSArray but in my code I only have NSMutableArray functionality...

View Controller.h:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *exampleMessages;
//added NSMutableArray property named exampleMessages
```

View Controller.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.exampleMessages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Example Message..", @"Example Message..",@"Example Message..",@"Example Message..",@"Example Message..", @"Example Message..",@"Example Message..",@"Example Message..", nil];
```

Am I creating the NSMutable array incorrectly??
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableArray` cannot be copy.

Change

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *exampleMessages;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *exampleMessages;
```

---

I've done this to myself at least three times so far. It's a real pain. I'm sorry to inform you there is no `mutableCopy` attribute for properties, I looked this up also.

The best answer I have for that is overriding `-setExampleMessages:`.

```
- (void)setExampleMessages:(NSMutableArray *)exampleMessages {
    _exampleMessages = [exampleMessages mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: @Cameron No problem. If my answer fixes your problem, then be sure to accept it.